# Deserialize nested json string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, javascriptserializer

my json data is like this

```
"{\"total_entries\":2,\"current_page\":1,\"total_pages\":1,\"per_page\":2,\"items\":[{\"workspace\":{\"background_color\":\"#ffedd3\",\"data_room\":false,\"default_sort\":\"alphabetical\",\"default_view\":\"list\",\"id\":330201,\"name\":\"MyWorkSpaceNew\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-05-08T05:54:25-07:00\",\"root_folder_id\":166325721,\"owner_id\":991101,\"is_owner\":true,\"effective_role\":\"Administrator\",\"audit_trail\":true,\"require_agreement\":false,\"agreement_accepted\":false}},{\"workspace\":{\"background_color\":\"white\",\"data_room\":false,\"default_sort\":\"alphabetical\",\"default_view\":\"list\",\"id\":343316,\"name\":\"qqq\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-05-12T22:34:08-07:00\",\"root_folder_id\":179855446,\"owner_id\":991101,\"is_owner\":true,\"effective_role\":\"Administrator\",\"audit_trail\":true,\"require_agreement\":false,\"agreement_accepted\":false}}]}"
```

i want to deserilize the json data
My C# code is like

```
workspacename data = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<workspacename>(responseText);
```

i want deserialize the data i am getting total_entries,items count,per_page but inside workspace i am getting every thing null

```
 public class workspacename
{
    public int total_entries { get; set; }//getting value
    public int current_page { get; set; }//getting value
    public int total_pages { get; set; }//getting value
    public int per_page { get; set; }//getting value
    public List<items> items { get; set; }// items count 2 but value null.

}

public class items
{
   // public List<workspace> workspace { get; set; }
    public string background_color { get; set; }
    public bool data_room { get; set; }
    public string default_sort { get; set; }
    public string default_view { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public int root_folder_id { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public bool is_owner { get; set; }
    public string effective_role { get; set; }
    public bool audit_trail { get; set; }
    public bool require_agreement { get; set; }
    public bool agreement_accepted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post the JSON value in full and also provide the workspace class to reproduce the issue.

Comment: hei i updated my code check it now

Comment: hei i didnt created workspace class is it required?

Comment: you have workspace within the items in the JSON. Please check the JSON string by applying in this url. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: i got it thanks  using this site `http://jsonpack.com/ModelGenerators/CSharp`

Answer (score 0):

use DataContractJsonSerializer instead :

you should define your data classes with attributes :

```
[DataContract]
public class workspacename
{
    [DataMember]
    public int total_entries { get; set; }//getting value
    [DataMember]
    public int current_page { get; set; }//getting value
...
```

and

```
[DataContract]
public class items
{
    [DataMember]
    public string background_color { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool data_room { get; set; }
...
```

then to deserilize you json object you should :

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(workspacename));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
 var asBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonObjectString);
 stream.Write(asBytes, 0, asBytes.Length);
 stream.Flush();
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 var yourDeserializedWorkspacename= (workspacename)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

Comment: How is it possible to deserializer JSON using datacontractserializer

Comment: I'm sure about that and the code is complete feel free to test it once :)

Answer (score 0):

With `Newtonsoft.Json` it would be simple:

```
workspacename obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<workspacename>(inputJson)
```

Worth noting that it is best to stick to naming conventions:

```
workspacename => WorkSpaceName
total_entries => TotalEntries
```